# extra http in http_proxy setting

Tags: proxy, settings

I've just installed Ubuntu on a desktop at work. All traffic flows through a proxy. For some reason Firefox works fine with the set proxy, but nothing else.

I checked the terminal with:
    set | grep -i proxy

and I saw that all my proxies have an extra http:// or https:// in there. How do I get rid of it. I entered my proxy as www-abc.company.com:12345. No idea where the extra http: could be coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine proxies as below in terminal , define these environment variables into the global /etc/environment file , so they will be always available

```
export http_proxy=abc.com:8080
export https_proxy=abc.com:8080
```